# assert a function pointer compatible with std::function

Tags: c++, std-function

What is the best practice to assert a callable is compatible with a `std::function`. Which tells whether the callable can be passed as argument where a relative `std::function` type is needed.

Examples:

```
int foo(int a) { return a; }
auto bar = [](int a)->int { return a; }
char baz(char a) { return a; }

compatible(foo, std::function<int(int)>) == true
compatible(bar, std::function<int(int)>) == true
compatible(baz, std::function<int(int)>) == true
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking, may be a signature of a function which will accept this callable would help(?) Trivially, this should be possible with `std::is_function<>` and `std::is_same<>`..

Comment: The left argument of the first and third examples are types, and of the second it is a value. That makes no sense.

Comment: Otherwise, `is_constructible` should be a trait that makes this check work.

Comment: @KerrekSB, you should make that the answer, `is_same<>` is too strong a check...

Comment: @Nim: I don't really understand the question, especially the lambda part :-(

Comment: I've modified the example code. Sorry for that dumb examples. @KerrekSB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your updated question, maybe the following would work:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool compatible(F const & f)
{
    return std::is_constructible<std::function<T>, F>::value;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << compatible<int(int)>(foo) << std::endl;
std::cout << compatible<int(int)>(bar) << std::endl;
std::cout << compatible<int(int)>(baz) << std::endl;
```